# Find out if a string is made up with a certain set of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, codemirror

How can I out if a string only contains a certain set of characters: `{` `A-Z` and `}` ?

For example

- `{VARIABLE}` => should return true
- `{VARiABLE}` => should be false, because there's a lowercase `i` inside
- `{ VARIABLE}` => should be false because there's a space etc.

**Oh, very important:**

the string MUST have at least one character between `{` and `}`, so:

- `{}` should be false too...

Comment: Should the format also always be `{...}`?

Comment: pmvdb yes, I forgot to mention that, tx: P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case use:

```
/^{[A-Z]+}$/.test(str);
```

The regexp represents any string of the format:

- First a `{`
- Then one or more capital letters
- Then a `}`

The `^...$` makes sure that the string should be exactly of this form, rather than a substring only (otherwise `test{AAA}` would match too).

Comment: +1 The only one yet to realise that the `{...}` are supposed to surround the text.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a good case to use regular expressions.  In particular, regexes allow one to match a range of characters - `[A-Z{}]` would match any character which is either an uppercase letter, `{`, or `}`.

**EDIT** based on new requirements - you want to match something that *starts* with a literal `{`, then has at least one character in the range `A-Z`, then a closing `}`.  Which gives the regex:

```
{[A-Z]+}
```

Thus you could match against the entire regex:

```
val input = "{VARIABLE}"
return input.test(/{[A-Z]+}/) // returns true

"{VARiABLE}".test(/{[A-Z]+}/) // returns false
"{ VARIABLE}".test(/{[A-Z]+}/) // returns false

"".test(/{[A-Z]+}/) // returns false - open bracket didn't match
"{}".test(/{[A-Z]+}/) // returns false - A-Z part didn't match
```

Comment: Note: to only validate the string, use the [test()](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/regexp_test.html) method rather than match().

Comment: Hmmm, `Oh, very important: the string MUST have at least one character between { and }` that's not solved by `+`, that's solved by restructuring your regex.

Comment: @Justin - good point, I'll add this when I update the answer.

Comment: @Justin, it actually isn't solved by `+`. Check the edits and check the time of my comment. You're out of synch, commenting according to a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex: `^[A-Z{}]+$`. It allows only `A-Z` and `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Do a negative regex match.  If you match something like `/[^A-Z{}]/` and get a success, then the string contains something that's "not allowed".

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex...

```
/^[{}A-Z]+$/

/^[{}A-Z]+$/.test("{VARIABLE}") // => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression.

[A-Z{}]*

Here the square brackets [] insist on what characters to be present and * says that this patter can repeat multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){                          
   $('#test_regex').click( function(){
      regex= /^{[A-Z]+}$/;
      str= $('#reginput').val();
      result= regex.test(str);
      if( result ){
        alert("It's the correct value, yes it's right");
      }else{
        alert("It's incorrect value.. You know");
      }
   });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="reginput"/>
<button id="test_regex">Check Value</button>
```

It will return alert("It's the correct value, yes it's right"), if value is **{UPPERCASELETTERS}**